# Notation question: (X,Y) and (Y,X) identically distributed?

Tags: probability

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with finite expectation (say, 1-dimensional), what does it mean to say that $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are both identically distributed?

From what I can see the assumption assumes that we have not fixed a basis. That is, if the basis is the standard basis, then this is automatic ($X(1,0) + Y(0,1)$ and $Y(1,0) + X(0,1)$ would both be identically distributed), but that the only worrying possibilities is when we are not using the standard basis, but instead something like $X(1,0) + Y(1,1)$. Then certainly it is not clear that $X(1,0) + Y(1,1)$ and $Y(1,0) + X(1,1)$ are identically distributed.

Have I interpreted this correctly?

Comment: Two $n$-dimensional random variables $U$ and $V$ are identically distributed if $P(U\in A)=P(V\in A)$ for all (nice) subsets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is automatic ($X(1,0) + Y(0,1)$ and $Y(1,0) + X(0,1)$ would both be identically distributed)

Not sure why you use "both" here but anyway "this" is not automatic.

Counterexample: Assume that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the rectangle $(0,a)\times(0,b)$, then $(Y,X)$ is uniformly distributed on the set $________$ hence $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed only in the special case $____$.

Comment: Just to be sure: were you able to fill the missing parts?

Comment: I think so. Aren't the missing parts $(0,b) \times (0,a)$ and $a=b$, respectively? Thank you for the instructive (counter)example!

Comment: They are. Perfect.